# Are these definitions of acquire and release fences incorrect?

Tags: concurrency, lock-free, memory-fences

In Joe Duffy's concurrent programming book he defines acquire and release fences like so:

*• Acquire fence. Ensures no load or store that comes after the fence will move befo re the fence. Instructions before it may still move after the fence.*

*• Release fence. Ensures no load or store that comes before the fence will move after the fence. Instructions after it may still happen before the fence.*

My question is: How can it be that an operation is allowed to happen before something, but is prevented from happening after. It's difficult to explain, but both these statements look like a chicken or the egg problem to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain that based on Java `volatile` semantics. Writing some value into a `volatile` variable **happens-before** this value can be read from this variable by other thread(s). How that is achieved? Let's take a closer look on some kind of instructions:

- Volatile read, i.e. reading a value from a `volatile` variable;
- Normal read, i.e. reading a value from a non-volatile variable;
- Volatile write;
- Normal write;

Now, Java memory model provides you with some behavior guarantees, one of them I wrote above. The question is - how is that achieved?

Well, `volatile` modifier forbids some kinds of reorderings - *volatile write* cannot be put before *normal write*, *volatile read* cannot be put after *normal read*.

How to connect that to your question? I'll try to formulate the answer based on what I wrote above.

- There are several types or reorderings that JVM and CPU can do to the instructions you write in your program;
- Memory barriers(fences) forbids some of that reorderings, depending on the fence type; speaking of your examples, *acquire fence* ensures that all operations that are going to happen before the fence, will not happen after it; similar to the second - all operations that are meant to happen after the fence, will not be moved before the fence; my examles with `volatile` illustrates that.